# Javers QueryBuilder Pagination Support

Tags: javers

UseCase :: How to write query using javers query builder that can support pagination while fetching audit's logs for api's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to write query is by using skip() and limit().

```
@Service
public class AuditService {

    @Autowired
    Javers javer;

    public List<Change> fetchAudits(String auditer,Integer offset,Integer limit) {
        return javer.findChanges(QueryBuilder.anyDomainObject().byAuthor(auditer).skip(offset).limit(limit).build());
    }

}
```